# Identify queries leading to seq_scan shown in pg_stat_user_tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have verified all the queries using `EXPLAIN`, and they show an index scan node in the plan.
But when i see stats in the table `pg_stat_user_tables` I see a non-zero value of `seq_scan`.

It is possible that PostgreSQL is doing a **bitmap heap scan** rather than just an **index scan**, but I am not completely sure.

I have following queries:

1. Does **bitmap heap scan** count as `seq_scan` in above stats table ?
2. How to identify the queries that perform the sequential scan?  The traffic to the database is non-uniform, hence monitoring `pg_stat_activity` is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A *bitmap index scan* is counted under `idx_scan`.

Finding the query that performs the sequential scan is harder.

Let's assume that the table is fairly big so that a sequential scan takes a certain time (for this answer, I assume at least 500 ms, but that may be different of couse). If the sequential scan is very short, you wouldn't and shouldn't worry.

Now put `auto_explain` into `shared_preload_libraries` and add the following parameters to `postgresql.conf`:

```
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 500
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
```

Then restart the server.

Now you will get the execution plans of all statements exceeding a duration of 500 ms in the PostgreSQL log, and you should be able to find the query.

By the way, sequential scans are not always something you should worry about. If they occur only rarely, that is usually fine. It might be that you are hunting your own database backup that uses `pg_dump`! Only expensive sequential scans that happen often are a problem.